# Using VStack with AsyncImage inside LazyVStack causes images to reload on scrolling

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, lazyvgrid

I'm trying to display a long list of images with titles using the new AsyncImage in SwiftUI. I noticed that when I put VStack around AsyncImage and scroll through images it's reloading images every time I scroll up or down. When there's no VStack I see no reloading and images seem to stay cached.

Is there a way to make VStack not to reload images on scrolling so I can add text under each image?

Here's a working example. Try scrolling with and without VStack.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {

    let url = URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/200/300")

    let columns: [GridItem] = [.init(.fixed(110)),.init(.fixed(110)),.init(.fixed(110))]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                ForEach(0..<20) { _ in
                    // VStack here causes to images to reload on scrolling
                    VStack {
                        AsyncImage(url: url) { image in
                            image
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        } placeholder: {
                            Image(systemName: "photo")
                                .imageScale(.large)
                                .frame(width: 110, height: 110)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What a bug with pretty basic layout! I think this makes `AsyncImage` not usable, it's strange that it wasn't reported earlier and fixed before release. Report it to [Feedback Assistant](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/) and consider switching to this [AsyncImage](https://github.com/V8tr/AsyncImage): it's pretty stable

Comment: Unfortunately,  AsyncImage does not cache the images. so each time it downloading an image on the reused cell.

Comment: I am using SDWebImage, still I have this issue. Anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I fully agree with you that this is a weird bug. I would guess that the reason it's happening has something to do with the way `LazyVGrid` chooses to layout views, and that using a `VStack` here gives it the impression there is more than one view to show. This is a poor job on Apple's part, but this is how I solved it: just put the `VStacks` internal to the `AsyncImage`. I'm not entirely sure what the original error is, but I do know that this fixes it.

```
struct MyTestView: View {
    let url = URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/200/300")
    let columns: [GridItem] = [.init(.fixed(110)),.init(.fixed(110)),.init(.fixed(110))]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                ForEach(0..<20) { i in
                    AsyncImage(url: url) { image in
                        VStack {
                            image
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            
                            Text("label \(i)")
                        }
                    } placeholder: {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: "photo")
                                .imageScale(.large)
                                .frame(width: 110, height: 110)
                            
                            Text("image broken")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Heads up that this doesn't seem to work anymore in iOS 16 and corresponding Xcode, Swift/UI versions.

Comment: is there any new solution for this. it is not working unfortunately.

Comment: Use image.image?.resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit) instead of image.resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)