# Reading from within a Package Dependency

Tags: caching, swiftui, package

After reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/69666892/18175514 and adding the package to my project, I changed my AsyncImage to CachedAsyncImage but it doesn't find CachedAsyncImage.

Is there something else I need to do when adding a package to make it find CashedAsyncImage?

*Current working code:*

```
AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://example.com/\(heroPicture)")) { phase in
    if let image = phase.image {
        image
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(width:10, height:10)
    } else if phase.error != nil {
        Text("Error")
    } else {
        ProgressView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added `import PACKAGE_NAME` to the top of your Swift file?

Comment: No, because I'm an noob.   That sorted it, thank you!   Post as an answer instead of a comment and I can mark it as solved by you :-)