# How do I cache images with SwiftData in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, caching, swiftui, swift-data

Say I have a `Person` model with a `var imageUrl: URL?` and I want to show a list of persons.

Using `AsyncImage` would load the image every time a view with it appears. I'd prefer to not use any packages. The `CacheAsyncImage` implementation from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69666892/6385925) is better, but still not perfect as it's not persisting them.

My idea is to use a dedicated Model for images:

```
@Model
class Person {
    var name: String
    var imageUrl: URL?
    @RelationShip var cachedImage: CachedImage?
}
```

```
@Model
class CachedImage {
    var person: Person?
    @Attribute(.unique) var imageUrl: URL?
    @Attribute(.externalStorage) var imageData: Data?
}
```

Afaik `AsyncImage` only provides an `Image` and I can't get the image data that way, so I'd probably have to load it myself and store the data accordingly:

```
// PersonListView

...
HStack {
    if let imageData = person.cachedImage?.imageData, let uiImage = UIImage(data: imageData) {
        Image(uiImage: uiImage)
    } else {
        Rectangle()
        .onAppear {
            loadPhoto(for: person)
        }
    }
    Text(person.name)
}
```

- **Is this an appropriate solution, or is there a better way to handle this?**
- **How would I detect the storage size of the images?**
- **How would I detect which images were accessed when, to remove the oldest ones?**

Comment: It is better to put the images in a folder using FileManager and then just save the custom part of the file name with SwiftData you have to create the logic for “last accessed”

Comment: @loremipsum Wouldn't it be better to let SwiftData handle storing the files by using `@Attribute(.externalStorage)`?

Comment: I don’t think so.  There would be much less processing.